# Play 2 framework 2.2.4 (ebean): pagination generates mutiple sql queries per one page when call Page<>.getList()

Tags: sql, playframework, pagination, playframework-2.0, ebean

We are using Play 2 Framework 2.2.4 (with eBean ORM integerated) in our project.
Our pagination looks like:

```
public static Page<Users> page(int pageNum, int pageSize) {
    Page<Users> page = find.where().findPagingList(pageSize).getPage(pageNum);
    return page;
}

...

Page<User> currentPage =  page(0, 10); // for example
```

and then in view:

```
@for(user <- currentPage.getList) {
    // display information for every user
    ...
}
```

When I turn on logging of SQL queries to console, I was surprised - to get user list for one page Ebean makes SQL request for **EVERY page**!

For our 329 users this means **33 total SQL queries**:

```
[debug] c.j.b.PreparedStatementHandle - select t0.user_id c0, t0.user_name c1, t0.first_name c2, t0.last_name c3, t0.user_full_name c4, t0.sex_id c5, t0.status c7, t0.role_id c8, t0.phone c9, t0.email c10 from users t0 order by user_id
limit 11
[debug] c.j.b.PreparedStatementHandle - select t0.user_id c0, t0.user_name c1, t0.first_name c2, t0.last_name c3, t0.user_full_name c4, t0.sex_id c5, t0.status c7, t0.role_id c8, t0.phone c9, t0.email c10 from users t0 order by user_id
limit 11 offset 10
[debug] c.j.b.PreparedStatementHandle - select t0.user_id c0, t0.user_name c1, t0.first_name c2, t0.last_name c3, t0.user_full_name c4, t0.sex_id c5, t0.status c7, t0.role_id c8, t0.phone c9, t0.email c10 from users t0 order by user_id
limit 11 offset 20
...
[debug] c.j.b.PreparedStatementHandle - select t0.user_id c0, t0.user_name c1, t0.first_name c2, t0.last_name c3, t0.user_full_name c4, t0.sex_id c5, t0.status c7, t0.role_id c8, t0.phone c9, t0.email c10 from users t0 order by user_id
limit 11 offset 320
```

With some experiments I discover, that this plenty of SQL queries appears exactly if method `Page<T>.getList()` is calling. Even if it is called alone without any other actions.

I don't understand - what is the reason for all that queries?

Is this some kind of a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play 2.2.4 [uses Ebean version 3.2.2](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.2.4/framework/project/Dependencies.scala#L29-L32), and this version of Ebean uses a ["fetch ahead" strategy](https://github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm/blob/avaje-ebeanorm-3.2.2/src/main/java/com/avaje/ebean/PagingList.java#L73-L83) to get **all the pages** when you call `getPage`.

You can change this by setting fetch ahead property to false, like this:

```
public static Page<Users> page(int pageNum, int pageSize) {
    Page<Users> page = find.where()
                           .findPagingList(pageSize)
                           .setFetchAhead(false)
                           .getPage(pageNum);
    return page;
}
```

Comment: Just a note that findPagingList() was used incorrectly enough that it was deprecated and ultimately removed (quite so time ago now).  findPagedList() has replaced it.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Notification> notifications = Ebean.find(Notification.class).where()
                .eq("notification_belong_to_user_id", userId)
                .order().desc("notificationDate")
                .findPagedList(pageNo, (int) pageSize)
                .getList();
```